# Numpy and Applying Method to a Column

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a numpy array that contains objects.

For example my array is:

`a = np.array({'a':1,'b':2},....,{'a':n,'b':n+1})`

The data is not that important, but what I need to do is for each column call a property on that object.

Using my dictionary example, I want to call `keys()` to print out a list of keys on that row and return as a numpy array:

`a[0].keys()`

If I were using `Pandas`, I could leverage `apply()` on the column and use lambda functions to do this.  For this case, I CANNOT use Pandas, so how can I do the same operation on a single numpy array column?

I tried using `apply_along_axis` but the lambda passes the `arr` as a whole not one row at a time, so I need to basically use a `for` loop inside my lambda to get my method.

`np.apply_along_axis(lambda b: b.keys(), axis=0, arr=self.data)`

The above code does not work! (I know this).

If there a way to do a `pandas.apply()` using a numpy array?

The desired result in this case would be N row numpy array with lists of [a,b] in them.

Comment: `a = np.array({'a':1,'b':2},....,{'a':n,'b':n+1})` - first, that's not a valid way to call `np.array` even with something sensible in place of the `....`. Second, why are you putting a pile of dicts in an array at all? NumPy is not designed to be convenient or efficient for this kind of use.

Comment: Also, on any Python version where `keys()` produces a list, dict order is not guaranteed.

Comment: It's just an example. I'm really holding multiple JSON responses in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A object array like this can treated as a list:

```
In [110]: n=2;a = np.array(({'a':1,'b':2},{'a':n,'b':n+1}))
In [111]: a
Out[111]: array([{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 2, 'b': 3}], dtype=object)
In [112]: [d.keys() for d in a]
Out[112]: [dict_keys(['a', 'b']), dict_keys(['a', 'b'])]
```

You could also use `frompyfunc` which will apply a function to all elements of an array (or broadcasted elements of several arrays)

```
In [114]: np.frompyfunc(lambda d:d.keys(),1,1)(a)
Out[114]: array([dict_keys(['a', 'b']), dict_keys(['a', 'b'])], dtype=object)
```

It returns an object array, which is fine in this case.  `np.vectorize` uses this function as well, but takes an `otypes` parameter.

As a general rule, iterating on an object dtype array is faster than iterating on a numeric array (since all it has to do is return a pointer), but slower than the equivalent iteration on a list.  Calculations on object dtype arrays are not as fast as the compiled numeric array calculations.